# PHP - Displaying random output more than once, prevent duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, random, include

I have the following code that I am using to randomly display PHP widgets from a folder:

```
<?php 
function random_widget($dir = 'wp-content/themes/zonza/elements')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
?>

<?php include random_widget();?>
<?php include random_widget();?>
<?php include random_widget();?>
```

random_widget(); outputs a URL, which I then use in the include function to display the widget.

The code randomly chooses between 6 php files and displays one randomly.  I include it 3 times to get 3 widgets.  However, I get the same widget displayed more than once sometimes.

What can I do to modify the code to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
function random_widget($dir = 'wp-content/themes/zonza/elements')
{
    static $files = false;
    if(!$files) $files=glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $key = array_rand($files);
    $file=$files[$key];
    unset($files[$key]);
    return $file;
}
?>
```

It works by removing the file returned from $files, and maintaining $files over multiple function calls (it only globs() on the first time you call the function)

Comment: This code reports an error.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on line 4

Comment: updated the code, I forgot that static variables in PHP cannot be initialized with an expression. Should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Declare files at the beginning of the page `$files = glob($dir . '/*.*');`
In random_widget, do this `unset($files[$file])` after you pull the value.

Comment: don't forget to pull $files into the namespace of the function with `global $files;` if you try this method

Comment: Yes, although a static variable actually would be better.

Answer (score 0):

`array_rand` takes a number `$num_req` as an optional second parameter which specifies the number of entries you want to pick. So add this parameter to `random_widget`, pass it to `array_rand` to get an array of keys instead of a single key, return the array of files, and then iterate over this array to include the widgets (instead of calling `random_widget` three times).

```
<?php 
function random_widget($num_req, $dir = 'wp-content/themes/zonza/elements')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $keys = array_rand($files, $num_req);

    $chosen = array();

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $chosen[] = $files[$key];
    }

    return $chosen;
}

$widgets = random_widget(3);
foreach($widgets as $widget) {
    include $widget;
}

?>
```

An advantage of this solution over the ones proposed in the other answers is that it is stateless: you can reuse the function in different contexts as much as you want.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: I like the idea of one function call to get as many widgets as you want - however this really only works well if all of the widgets are together in one spot. My solution allows for random_widget() to be called from anywhere without much fuss.